# how to change column If another column has a special word on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long dataframe and I want to apply for every rows, I want to do this if 'word' in column 1 I want to change column2, but word will get dictionary.key, and column2 will get dictionary.value

`di = {'btw':'By The Way','afk':'Away From Keyboard'}`

[image: click to see example]

Comment: You can use the string [replace()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace#:~:text=replace()%20parameters,substring%20with%20the%20new%20substring) method to achieve this if that's what you're looking for? Simply run this replacement with your table of words to replace for every column.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post them as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply`:

```
df['temp'] = df['sentences'].apply(lambda x:[j for j in di.keys() if j in x]
df['shortly'] = df['temp'].apply(lambda a:','.join([di[key] for key in a]))

df.drop(['temp'],axis = 1,inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          sentences             shortly
0  btw I have to go          By The Way
1      i am afk now  Away From Keyboard
```

The above would work even if there are multiple short forms in a single sentence, only the output will be separated with `,` in `shortly` column (you can change the separator in second apply statement).

eg.

```
          sentences        temp                        shortly
0  btw I have to go       [btw]                     By The Way
1      i am afk btw  [btw, afk]  By The Way,Away From Keyboard
```

If the short-forms can be a different case than in the dictionary, then just add `.lower()` in the first apply statement like so:

```
df['temp'] = df['sentences'].apply(lambda x:[j for j in di.keys() if j in x.lower()]
```

keep all the shortforms in dictionary as lower case though